# preg_repace single quote issue.

Tags: php, regex

I want to replace single quotes with backslash single quote.     Tried the below php code when I do a echo it displays properly but when I do a error_log it displays an additional backslash.  Not sure whether I am doing anything wrong or error_log function is escaping it.

```
$cont="a'b";
// display a\'b
echo preg_replace("/'/", "\\'" , $cont);
// displays a\\'b in apache error log file
error_log(preg_replace("/'/", "\\'" , $cont);
```

Comment: `echo str_replace("'", "\'", $cont);`

Comment: addslashes() function

Comment: The regex engine needs to see: `\\'` so the regex string needs to be: `"/\\\\'/""` - since the string interpolation eats the first backslash.

Comment: None of these comments so far work. Furthermore, I don't think PHP will help, because I think it's something to do with the server, in my case Apache 2.4. I notice that even using the ASCII code `error_log(chr(92));` ends up with two backslashes \\ in the log.

Comment: @JeffPuckettII If there is an issue, it should be PHP specific. It doesn't relate to server at all.

Comment: Nope. you've got a *bug,* friend!  Try looking at what you've posted above, *v-e-r-r-r-r-r-ry carefully ...*

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your code. You're missing a closing bracket on last line where you call `error_log()`:

Full code:

```js
$cont="a'b";
// display a\'b
echo preg_replace("/'/", "\\'" , $cont);
// displays a\\'b in apache error log file
error_log(preg_replace("/'/", "\\'" , $cont));
```

Screen shot:[image]